# serving client + socket io from backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Serving a vue js + socket io client from a node js server (with socket io obviously)

while developing i was connecting and awaiting calls from localhost:8000

```
new Websocket(
    new Server(server, {
        cors: {
            origin: "http://localhost:8000",
            methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        },
    }),
);
```

but now, obviously, there is no longer localhost:8000 and I am serving my client's dist/index.html through my webserver as a static file

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../client/dist")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../client/dist/index.html"));
});
```

I feel like I am missing something really really simple? am I supposed to host my client on a different "web server" if i want to use the socket.io functionality?

as in create a simple web server for the client - and serve it from there on port 8000? and run my own server seperatly ? on port 3000?

I'm hosting this on an EC2 container on aws

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - I need to connect to the machine's ip instead of localhost through the client's app - cause localhost:3000 doesn't actually exist...otherwise everything else is ok